# Unable to Debug Protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, jasmine

I can't debug my protractor tests anymore.  I am using a new machine and the same tests can be debugged on my older machine without any changes.

- Windows 8.1 (same)
- Protractor 1.3.1
- Selenium-Webdriver 2.43.1
- Jasmine 2.3.0
- Java 1.8.0u45

This is very frustrating because I will enter the following line on the command prompt and I never get a chance to enter any user input.

```
c:\development\angularApp\src\app> protractor end2end.conf.js --debug
```

If however I use the following command line then the debugging process works normally.

```
c:\development\angularApp\src\app> protractor debug end2end.conf.js
```

I have seen several examples that indicate that the first way is the better way to go but it does not offer me any input.  Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Not directly related, but why are you still using `1.3.1`, it is `2.0.0` nowadays, upgrade.

Comment: We still use 1.3.1 because 2.0 will break most of our end 2 end tests.  I don't recall now why but I do remember one member of our team upgraded and we started getting hundreds of failures.

Comment: I agree there are backwards incompatibility changes but it is still worth upgrading.